# Chrome extension disable/crash after ctrl-R in developers mode

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wrote some custom extension for google chrome but sometimes when I press reload link on extension or Ctrl-R it goes to disabled mode and after few minutes Automatically return to enabled. I cannot find the reason what the problem may be. Can developers mode be the reason of this issue?

[image]

My manifest looks like this

[image]

Comment: Okay. Details, please. The extension is loaded as unpacked? What do you call "disabled mode"? The "Enabled" checkbox? The "(Inactive)" next to background page? Could you provide a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Yes I load extension from directory.

Comment: this is a screen shoot

Comment: I add disabled image

Comment: I use also to much console.log function in files can this cause this problem

Comment: This is interesting. When you reload an extension (and reloading the `chrome://extensions/` page automatically reloads ALL extensions), it briefly goes to Disabled as Chrome unloads and loads it again. So, questions: 1) Can you add your manifest to the question? 2) Do you use `runtime.onUpdateAvailable` in your code? 3) Do you have a lot of other extensions installed? 4) Do you ever have problems with slow reads from the drive `E:`? Perhaps it spins down and has to spin up again..

Comment: _Psst, when you add some code to the question, add it as text (preceeded by 4 spaces on each line), code-in-image is very frowned upon.._

Comment: 1) I added manifest.json
2) I dont use runtime.onUpdateAvailable
3) I have other extension instaled but not to many
4) I use SSD drive I have no reading problems yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125989/discussion-between-xan-and-baxri).